# Inserção de múltiplas instâncias não funciona via DbSet.AddRange() no Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework

Gostaria de ajuda para conseguir resolver uma inserção de múltiplas instâncias de uma classe `C#`. Eu possuo um `IList<Operacao>` para salvar no banco via `Entity Framework Core` e tenho utilizado `DbSet.AddRange(entity)` para a persistência da lista de objetos. No entanto, apenas o último objeto da lista é salvo no banco. Todos os demais não perdidos ou ignorados.

Abaixo demonstro o meu código:

```
public virtual async Task AdicionarVarios(IList<TEntity> entity)
{
    DbSet.AddRange(entity);
    await SaveChanges();
}

public async Task<int> SaveChanges()
{
    return await Db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

O que pode estar errado ou faltando para que eu consiga persistir toda a lista de objetos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri a solução para o problema e irei compartilhar para que possa ajudar outros desenvolvedores com a mesma questão. Eu simplesmente adicionei a seguinte linha de código `DbSet.AttachRange(entity);`. Isso permitiu que todos os objetos da lista fossem devidamente persistidos no banco de dados.

O resultado ficou o seguinte:

```
public virtual async Task AdicionarVarios(IList<TEntity> entity)
{
    DbSet.AttachRange(entity);
    DbSet.AddRange(entity);
    await SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

a função parece estar correta mas como so tem um pedaço do codigo não da para saber bem ao certo, mas voce poderia fazer um foreach e gravar um registro por vez ja que voce disse que esta gravando somente o ultimo,talvez resolva.

```
public virtual async Task AdicionarVarios(IList<TEntity> entity)
{
foreach(var item in entity)
{
    DbSet.AddRange(item);
    await SaveChanges();
}

}
```